# How to install the magento custom created module in magento 2 on localhost using command line in window?

Tags: magento2, module, installation

how  I can install the Magento 2 custom created Module using Command line in localhost.

```
php bin/magento:enable vendor_modulename
```

tried this but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run command below,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Remove var folder and check.